# Runtime error 94 invalid use of null ColorIndex

Tags: vba, excel

I get the error `runtime error 94 invalid use of null` with the following code:

```
Sub test()
    With Selection.Interior
        MsgBox (.ColorIndex)
   End With
End Sub
```

I select a cell that consists of two merged cells (horizontally and has a color with `ColorIndex` 15 (it's purple).

I tried running the code on other cells and it's running fine. What could cause this problem here?

Comment: I cannot replicate. I just did created the scenario and ran `?Selection.Interior.ColorIndex` in immediate window and it returned a number. However, ColorIndex of 15 is grey on my system. Maybe there's a weird format scheme that is causing issue? What happens if you try just `(.Color)`?

Comment: FWIW the parens around `.ColorIndex` are superfluous. [See why](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201705251504152022667).

Comment: If selected range have more than 1 color then it will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occured when you tried to show a `Null` with `MsgBox`. That originated from selecting two - or more - cells with different `.Interior.ColorIndex`.

`Selection.Interior.ColorIndex` will return `Null` if they are of different color indexes. I suggest to loop through the selection - or pass the selection to a range variable - before you call them with `MsgBox`.

```
Dim rCell As Range
For Each rCell In Selection
  MsgBox rCell.Interior.ColorIndex
Next
```

or

```
Dim rCell As Range              '<~ variable that will loop
Dim rSelection As Range         '<~ variable that will hold selection
Set rSelection = Selection      '<~ pass selection to variable
For Each rCell In rSelection
  MsgBox rCell.Interior.ColorIndex
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped.